# php-fpm corrupts source code after child SIGKILL

Tags: php-fpm, 500-error

Strange situation happens, about once a month on the server one of the php-fpm child processes is forced to shut down (error log - `WARNING: [pool www] child 20651 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 1788.435071 seconds from start`), after that in any of the hundreds of running php scripts an absolutely arbitrary character is changed, which causes error 500 until php-fpm is restarted.

As far as I understand, after SIGKILL for some reason cached php script source code is corrupted, but how is it possible?

What could be the reason for the arbitrary source code change and how to avoid it?

Comment: someone doing a rowhammer attack perhaps?

Comment: @Jasen I don't think that's possible. The server is virtual and hosted by a large and reliable cloud provider.

Comment: virtual only increases the attack service,